# Python Dataframe with list field to bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I have a problem with loading Datafrom to bigquery with list structure field.
I looked for answers in stack and google but all of the answers don't work.

I created a scheme for the data in json and the schema for the problematic field looks that:

```
{
  'name': 'field_name',
  'type': 'record',
  'mode': 'repeated',
  'fields': [{
    'name': 'list',
    'type': 'string',
    'mode': 'nullable'
  }]
}
```

also, I tried:

```
{
  'name': 'field_name',
  'type': 'string',
  'mode': 'repeated',
}
```

The data from API look that:

```
{
  'field_name': [el1, el2, el3],
  ...
}
```

When I convert the data from API to DF, the `field_name` column is a string in accordance with the `string-repeated` schema but when I load the data to BQ table, the elements from the column are split letter by letter, what is not expected.
For the `record-repeated` schema I get the error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Could not convert 'el1' with type str: was expecting tuple of (key, value) pair
```

Also, I tried to use `SchemaField` from bigquery library but the result was the same as for json schema.

I use `google-cloud-bigquery` and `load_table_from_dataframe` methods.

I don't know what I do wrong so maybe someone figure out any solution.

**EDIT**

There is a method that returns client and job config

```
def get_bigquery_client_and_config(
        self, write_disposition: WriteDispositionEnum
    ) -> Tuple[bigquery.Client, bigquery.LoadJobConfig]:
        bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=self.project_id)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            autodetect=False,
            write_disposition=write_disposition.value,
            schema=self.schema,
        )
        return bq_client, job_config
```

There is a code that sends the data to BQ:

```
destination_id = f"{self.dataset_id}.{table_id}"
bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
  df, destination_id, job_config=job_config
).result()
```

The scheme for the problematic field is above.

Comment: can you please add you code what causing the issue ?

Comment: I added the code as an edit